# When running gnome-tweak-tool from a command window in gnome?

Tags: fedora, gnome3

What is the command when running gnome-tweak-tool from a command window in gnome?

I am learning the keyboard shotcutkeys on gnome3 without a mouse.

if you let me know, i'll appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

The command is `gnome-tweaks` from a shell command-line (a terminal window).

However, you can also hit the Overview key (usually the "Windows" key on your keyboard) and start typing "tweaks" — for me it comes up after just typing t-w — and then hit enter.